# User is not authenticated message in response after succesful authenticateUser method and tokens generated in cognito-identity-js

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-sdk-js, amazon-cognito-identity-js

User is not authenticated message is getting in the response while i'm trying to do `updateUserAttribute`, `deleteUser` (authenticated user), `verifyUserAttribute`, after succesful login `authenticateUser` method is called and tokens are generated.

**Following is my authenticateUser Code:**

```
import { CognitoUser, AuthenticationDetails } from "amazon-cognito-identity-js";
import Pool from "./UserPool";
const AWS = require('aws-sdk/global');

const authenticate = async (Username, Password) => (
    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const user = new CognitoUser({ Username, Pool });
      const authDetails = new AuthenticationDetails({ Username, Password });

      user.authenticateUser(authDetails, {
        onSuccess: data => {
          console.log('onSuccess:', data);
          AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1';

          AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
            IdentityPoolId: 'us-east-1:********-****-****-****-************', // your identity pool id here
            Logins: {
              // Change the key below according to the specific region your user pool is in.
              'cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/us-east-1_xxxxxxxxx': data
                .getIdToken()
                .getJwtToken(),
            },
          });
          //refreshes credentials using AWS.CognitoIdentity.getCredentialsForIdentity()
          AWS.config.credentials.refresh(error => {
            if (error) {
              console.error('refresh err: ',error);
            } else {
              // Instantiate aws sdk service objects now that the credentials have been updated.
              // example: var s3 = new AWS.S3();
              console.log('Successfully logged!');
            }
          });
          
          resolve(data);
        },

        onFailure: err => {
          console.error('onSignInFailure:', err);
          reject(err);
        },

        newPasswordRequired: data => {
          console.log('newPasswordRequired:', data);
          resolve(data);
        }
      });
    })
)
export default authenticate;
```

Any steps that I'm missing after generating tokens and storing credentials in AWS.config.credentials